# Insert image in Google Fusion Table with REST API

Tags: python, google-api, google-fusion-tables

Can I insert image with Google Fusion Table's API?

I've insert normal data and it's OK:

```py
cols = ['title', 'comments', 'Location', 'Date', 'picture']
values = ['t1', 'c1', 'l1', 'd1', 'p1']
fusion.insertRow(cols, values)
```

but to insert an image, I sent it as below:

```py
img_blob = open('/home/mehdi/logo.png', 'rb').read()
cols = ['title', 'comments', 'Location', 'Date', 'picture']
values = ['t1', 'c1', 'l1', 'd1', img_blob]
fusion.insertRow(cols, values)
```

and I got 413 error:

`413: Your client issued a request that was too large. that’s all we know.`

I've read Google Fusion Table API documentation but I didn't see any note about it.

Comment: You only should change the request Get  by Post, maybe the content is very long. Also chose a content type adapted to what you want to send.

Comment: @juliansalas : I send the request with POST and content type in corresponding column is image :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to upload an image in the Google Fusion Table because you can do anything with its URL.

So just send your image URL instead of itself.